# Deleting a current revision

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd like to delete the current revision (made in error by an admin) for a list of nodes.

On a test site - I've looked into re-using core functionality in my script, reverting to a previous revision, then deleting the remaining revision. But the revert creates a new one itself.

I'd really like to set it so it's like the most recent revision never happened, and is gone entirely. Our system shows a history of node changes and I don't want it to show up there (and also don't want to hack the display to suppress these few erroneous revisions etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: [`node_revision_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_revision_delete/7) would probably be the way to go

Comment: It appears to not cater for deleting the current revision `if($revision_id == $node->vid) {return FALSE;}`

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I think the point of revisions is to keep an accurate history of what's happened to the content, so creating a new revision when you revert makes absolute sense. I get the feeling you'd need to do some manual manipulation of the node/node_revision and field tables to accomplish what you need

Comment: We've got a script here that we use for something similar, but it's quite mungy :-) i thought this would be a good opportunity to think of something cleaner. but sometimes it will always be messy when you are fighting the intended usage!

Comment: Heh, love that word "mungy", it covers all manner of ills :) There might well be a cleaner solution, I think under-the-hood it's just going to do what your script does but if there's an 'official' solution I guess at least you know it's robust and tested